# How can I connect to php files and the database in emulator

Tags: android

I use `wamp server` in my windows. Also I have an android program that it should connect to database. My database and php files are in `wamp server`.

How can I access them when my program runs in emulator?

Comment: Please explain more in detail what you need. You dont how to connect? You dont know how to make the emulator have networking? Be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

First, set up `wamp server`. after that you have to locate your php files in a folder in www folder, for example, your path must be `C:\wamp\www\myphpfiles`.
so, your database must be uploaded in wamp.

Finally if you are trying on windows or linux get your ip address, you must to have a wireless conection. you can get your ip opening a cmd and set `ipconfig` or `ifconfig`, depens your SO. locate youe ip address v4. 
in your java class you have to set this ip to send yout request, for example:

```
String url = "http://134.45.6.7/myphpfiles/myfile.php"
```